Is there a way to select a point using the coordinates instead of the dimensions in xarray
I want to do what
.sel(lon=lon, lat=lat)

does except here lon and lat vary with each other so they are coordinates and not directly the dimensions.
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:              (x: 1536, y: 1440)
Coordinates:
    lon                  (x, y) float64 -8.387 -8.372 -8.358 ... 16.65 16.67
    lat                  (x, y) float64 37.28 37.28 37.28 ... 54.92 54.92 54.92 

